# GTM: track clics on banner slides as events

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need to generate events each time a user clicks on any of the slides of the banner of the home page of this site:

https://www.lacuracao.pe/

I've asked a developer to put ids to each slide, in order to make it easier to track each banner separatly as an event when its clicked.

My click trigger is set to fire on slide with `id="banner-home-01"`, but the tag won't fire. This is the last slide, not the first one as one would expect.

**Could it be that it's inside another divs? (even using the id attribute to target it's clicks?)**

My clicks listeners and linkclick listeners are working:

[image]

**My trigger:**

[image]

**My tag:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div width="100%" class="banner-slider-18 body-banner-01" id="banner-home-01">

    <a href="/curacao/celulares-lc"><div width="100%" class="fondo">

        <!--<div>

            <div class="linkeo">
            <a href="/curacao/tv-samsung-ultra-hd-smart-55-un-55nu7090g-un-55nu7090g-p"> 
            <button>compra</button>
            </a>
            </div>

            <div class="linkeo">
            <a href="/curacao/tv-samsung-ultra-hd-smart-55-un-55nu7090g-un-55nu7090g-p">
            <button>compra</button>
            </a>
            </div>

        </div>-->
    </div></a>

</div>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

The tag appears in the Debugger Summary as not fired, and when clicked it shows:

[image]

This is an image of the details, but It doesn't show why it didn't fire:

[image]

Comment: in the GTM debugger, click into the "GA-banner-home-events" tag and it will tell you why it didn't fire.

Comment: @XTOTHEL please, see my update.

Answer (score 0):

if you look in the debugger at the event gtm.linkClick and look at the variables you can see that the variable is an emtpy string, thats why your tag isn't firing. Your developer needs to add an id to the link itself, so the Click ID will be filled (see screenshot with the id test). After that the Click ID field will be filled with the id.

[image]

[image]

Another tip for you if you want to see why a tag isn't firing you have to select the event you want to inspect on the left side, for example a click and then click on the tag that wasn't firing. If you scroll down to Firing Triggers, you see what condition hasn't been fulfilled.
[image]

Comment: ty. So it would be: `<a id='banner-home-01' href="/curacao/celulares-lc">`. As you can see the link already has  an id 'test', I guess I'll ask the developer to change it. ty again.

Comment: Yes the id would be "banner-home-01' as you described. The id="test" doesn't exist, I did that with the chrome web developer tools to show you how it could look like :)